# Smallest number with digits product of n

Tags: java

I need to find the smallest number which digit numbers product is equal to a given num.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class timus_1014_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = new int[10]; // eskan ban@  chem imanum inchi a statik,
        int prod = 1;
        int j = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; ++i){
            if (n % i == 0) {
                arr[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
        prod =  prod * arr[j];

        System.out.print(prod);

    }
}
```

Something is wrong with the logic, whats is the problem when I input `10` it should give `25` but it gives `0`. Please give ideas of how to make a program find a number which digits product is a given num.

Comment: Shouldn't prod be either a static attribute or a local variable of prime ? Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: yes my code doesn't compile and i don't know what to do

Comment: @halu can you give an example of what is required?

Comment: so, if the input is 10 - we get 25 because the smallest integer which digits product is 10 is 25

Comment: What should happen if the input is a prime number bigger than 9? For example F(17)=?, F(11)=?

Comment: @Athmos i guess no solution exists for numbers whose prime factors > 9

Comment: Related: [Algorithm to find integer such that product of its digits is N](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403720/algorithm-to-find-integer-such-that-product-of-its-digits-is-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you need a number whose product of digits equals a number N. Since you asked for new algorithm , you can chck following code.

#### Logic:

Note : For number whose prime factors are less than 10

1. Get all factors from 9 -> 2
2. add to list
3. print in reverse or use stack instead of list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int num = in.nextInt();

        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int p = 9; p >= 2; p--) {
            while (num % p == 0) {
                num /= p;
                lst.add(p);
            }
        }

        String smallestNumber = "";
        for (int i = lst.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            smallestNumber = smallestNumber + lst.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Smallest number : " + smallestNumber);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Enter number
10
Smallest number : 25

Enter number
144
Smallest number : 289

Enter number
12
Smallest number : 26
```

Comment: thank you, i have not gone such further but i will try to get this, and i have problem 
Error:(13, 43) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Comment: @halu I used java 7. For java 6 just replace line with List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: For the 144 example, wouldn't 289 be the smallest number?

Comment: @Athmos Thanks, i fixed that. Forgot about grouping 2s to form 8 as per algo.

Comment: There are still some issues, consider the input 12. Your algorithm will return '34' but the smallest possible result is '26'.

Comment: @Athmos Thanks, fixed it again with simpler solution as solution may not exist if prime factors of number exceed 10.

Comment: yeah, solved it myself in the meantime xD. Looks like we're doing homework for @halu.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at each error is fix it one by one.  I also suggest you use an IDE which will show you the errors and you type and will help ensure you don't have an overwhelming number of errors and you can see if those error disappear based on your corrections.

BTW Often when you use an array for a short piece of code, it can often be eliminate as I suspect it can be removed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can not access non-static members of class. 
In your case prod is member variable of class but not static. To fix the error , try to make prod as static.

```
private static int prod = 1;
```

I would prefer , to make it local variable if no other method is using it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you need to create an object of the particular class to call a particular method associated with it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class DigPro {
static int[] arr = new int[10]; // eskan ban@  chem imanum inchi a statik,
int prod = 1;
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
DigPro obj = new DigPro();
obj.prime(in.nextInt());

}



public void prime(int n){
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i){
   for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
       if (n % i == 0) {

           arr[j] = i;

       }
   prod =  prod * arr[j];
   }

}
System.out.print(prod);
}

}
```

Here you need to create an object say obj of DigPro class and then call prime(int n) method with that object. Also your division is startint with zero which is changed to one

Comment: thanks, i have not mentioned that, but still brings 3 errors, i still have problems with static and no-static

Comment: Try the code that I posted here. It works without errors. Although I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Error:(24, 12) java: non-static variable prod cannot be referenced from a static context such errors occur

Comment: then use an object, in my case obj along with prod.  for ex System.out.println(obj.prod); It will work or else you are doing it wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In above code you are increasing `j` after the assigning value to `arr[j]`.You should do the following:-

```
prod = prod * arr[j-1];
```

Here it will multiply `prod` with last array updated. That is why you are getting zero. And for your another question **find the smallest number which digit numbers product is equal to a given num** has similar answer at this [**link**](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5712388493934592).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is actually a pretty interesting problem, I took the time to come up with a correct solution for all possible integer inputs.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
        int number = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        Stack<String> factors = new Stack<>();
        if(number==0){
            factors.push("0");
        }else if(number==1){
            factors.push("1");
        }else{
            for(int f=9;f>1;f--){
                while(number%f==0){
                    factors.push(Integer.toString(f));
                    number/=f;
                }
            }
        }

        if(number<0){
            factors.push("-");
        }

        if(number>9){
            System.out.println("This is impossible.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Smallest Number:");
            while(!factors.empty()) System.out.print(factors.pop());
        }
    }
}
```